# how to add multiple unrelated int values to array

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist

I have a bunch of integers, more than 20, some of them a sequential, like from 100 to 109, but others are not, is there a efficient way to group them into a array? I tried use `ArrayList`and then `list.toArray`, but then i need to use too many `add` method. is there a more efficient way? thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly you have some predefined values and you want to build an efficient array. Easiest way would be to declare it in the following way:

```
int[] array = {45, 47, 84, 29};
```

While will produced an int[] (inferred from left hand side)

Comment: better than doing 50 .adds if your looking for performance. and easier than doing `new int[50]; array[0] = 45; array[1] = 47` If there is a source for the data or a generator then it may be easier but you stated there was not and you clearly want to use arrays in the most efficient way so that's the solution I provided. Feel free to expand on what you want and I will try to improve my answer.

Comment: Where are those 50 numbers and in what format are they written?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you could use [Arrays.asList()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#asList%28T...%29)

```
List<Integer> al = Arrays.asList(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8); // keep adding ints.
```